# Examples of hidden gems

Tags: history, master-games

For the moment, I have a hard time finding time for chess due to studies, so for the time being, chess has to be a purely recreational activity for me. What I'm looking for are examples of beutiful games that may or may not be very well known.

For example, I like the following game played between Yuri S. Gusev (white) and Yuri Averbakh(or E. Auerbach, depending on the source) in 1946. In the game, White's winning idea could be described as(just slightly bending the truth):

- Give your opponent a rook
- Afterwards, give your opponent a queen, to balance things out
- After that, dominate your opponent, and win

The game:

```
[Date "1946"]
[White "Gusev, Yuri"]
[Black "Averbakh, Yuri or Auerbach, E."]
[Result "1-0"]

[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w - - 0 1"]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 g6 6. Be2 Nc6 7. Nb3 Bg7 8. O-O Be6 9. f4 Rc8 10. f5 Bd7 11. g4 Ne5 12. g5 Ng8 13. Nd5 f6 14. Be3 b6 15. Nd4 Kf7 16. c3 Qe8 17. Ne6 Bxe6 18. fxe6 Kf8 19. Nxf6 Nxf6 20. gxf6 Bxf6 21. Bh6 Kg8 22. Rxf6 exf6 23. Qxd6 Rc6 24. Qxe5 fxe5 25. Rf1 Rc8 26. Bd1 Rc4 27. Bb3 b5 28. Bxc4 bxc4 29. b3 a5 30. bxc4 Qe7 31. Kg2 Qa3 32. Rf2 Qe7 33. Rf1 g5 34. Rf5 g4 35. c5 Qd8 36. c6 Qe7 37. c7 1-0
```

The purpose behind this post is that I would like to generate a collection of nice and inspiring games on this site, which I haven't really found yet. I know that it's quite subjective to determine whether a game is beautiful or not, but I feel like stuff like this might bring something valuable to this community.

Comment: Nice idea. Maybe it can be moved to community. It's likely to be closed.

Comment: @TonyEnnis Yeah, I suspected that might happen, actually. How is a question/entry moved to community?

Comment: Ed will probably chime in soonish.

Answer (score 3):

Gusev - Averbach is a good start; it reminds me of the following game, where less material is sacrificed (only a knight) but more pieces are dominated:

## The immortal Zugzwang game

(taken from [here](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1102400))

```
[Date "1923"]
[White "Saemisch, Friedrich"]
[Black "Nimzowitsch, Aron"]
[Result "0-1"]

[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w - - 0 1"]

1. d4 {Notes by Nimzowitsch's "My System"} Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 b6 4. g3 Bb7 5. Bg2 Be7 6. Nc3 O-O 7. O-O d5 8. Ne5 c6 {Safeguards the position} 9. cxd5 cxd5 10. Bf4 a6 {Protects the oupost station c4, i.e., by ...a6 and ...b5.} 11. Rc1 b5 12. Qb3 Nc6 {The ghost! With noiseless steps he presses on towards c4.} 13. Nxc6 {Samisch sacrifices two tempi (exchange of the tempo-eating Knight on e5 for the Knight which is almost undeveloped) merely to be rid of the ghost.} Bxc6 14. h3 Qd7 15. Kh2 Nh5 {I could have supplied him with as yet a second ghost by ...Qb7 and ...Knight-d7-b6-c4, but I wished to turn my attention to the King's side.} 16. Bd2 f5 {!} 17. Qd1 b4 {!} 18. Nb1 Bb5 19. Rg1 Bd6 20. e4 fxe4 {! This sacrifice, which has a quite surprising affect, is based upon the following sober calculation: two Pawns and the 7th rank and an enemy Queen's wing which cannot be disentangled - all this for only one piece!} 21. Qxh5 Rxf2 22. Qg5 Raf8 23. Kh1 R8f5 24. Qe3 Bd3 25. Rce1 h6 {!! A brilliant move which announces the Zugzwang. White has not a move left. If, e.g., Kh2 or g4, then R5f3. Black can now make waiting moves with his King, and White must, willy-nilly, eventually throw himself upon the sword.} 0-1
```

Comment: This game is just unreal. I remember the first time I saw it; I couldn't believe it was true, and then I sat down and looked at all possible moves for White, and realized that Nimzowitsch was completely right. Really inspiring stuff.

Answer (score 2):

"Positional" Queen Sacs? Hidden Gems? Surely we must mention Mr Nezhmetdinov here!

```
[Event "Rostov"]
[Site "Rostov"]
[Date "1962.??.??"]
[EventDate "?"]
[Round "?"]
[Result "1-0"]
[White "Rashid Gibiatovich Nezhmetdinov"]
[Black "Oleg L Chernikov"]
[ECO "B35"]
[WhiteElo "?"]
[BlackElo "?"]
[PlyCount "65"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 g6 5. Nc3 Bg7 6. Be3
Nf6 7. Bc4 O-O 8. Bb3 Ng4 9. Qxg4 Nxd4 10. Qh4 Qa5 11. O-O Bf6
12. Qxf6 Ne2+ 13. Nxe2 exf6 14. Nc3 Re8 15. Nd5 Re6 16. Bd4
Kg7 17. Rad1 d6 18. Rd3 Bd7 19. Rf3 Bb5 20. Bc3 Qd8 21. Nxf6
Be2 22. Nxh7+ Kg8 23. Rh3 Re5 24. f4 Bxf1 25. Kxf1 Rc8 26. Bd4
b5 27. Ng5 Rc7 28. Bxf7+ Rxf7 29. Rh8+ Kxh8 30. Nxf7+ Kh7
31. Nxd8 Rxe4 32. Nc6 Rxf4+ 33. Ke2 1-0
```

Comment: I've never seen this one before, although I knew that Nezhmetdinov made stuff like this work. It's actually quite amazing.